# How to redirect at the route level, not at the action level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, redirect, routes

I'd like to redirect `campaigns#index` to `newsletters#index` at the route level (`config/routes.rb`).

**config/routes.rb**

```
#match '/campaigns' => redirect('/newsletters')             # something like this
resources :campaigns do
  put 'send_preview'
  put 'send_actual'
  put 'unschedule'
end
```

The following test succeeds, though again, I want it to succeed due to route-level redirect, not action-level redirect.

**test/functional/campaigns_controller_test.rb**

```
class CampaignsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

test "get index should redirect to newsletters" do
  get :index
  assert_redirected_to newsletters_path
end
```

**app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb**

Once the route-level redirection works, I would like to get rid of this action:

```
def index
  redirect_to newsletters_path
end
```

Comment: `match '/campaigns' => redirect('/newsletters')` is how you do redirects from routes.rb. What are you asking?

Comment: I'm not sure what was going wrong at the time, but yes, my commented line does indeed work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commented line

```
match '/campaigns' => redirect('/newsletters')
```

is working, and also

```
match '/campaigns', to: 'newsletters#index'
```

is working too.